# Objects are not valid as a React child (Conversion of object to String)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The development server displays the following error when running the React Code "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_seconds, _nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

The error is shown in the following line

```
this.setState({screams:res.data});
```

However, research of similar problems shows that the error occurs when passing the object as a property

**Home Page**

```
class home extends Component {
    state={
        screams : null
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('/screams')
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res.data);
            *this.setState({
                screams:res.data               
            });*

        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }
    render() {
        let recentScreamsMarkup= this.state.screams ? (
            this.state.screams.map((scream) => <Scream scream={scream}/>)
            ) : <p>Loading...</p>
        return(
            <Grid container spacing={5}>
                <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
                    {recentScreamsMarkup}
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
                    <p>Profile</p>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}
```

**The Scream Component**

```
 class Scream extends Component {
    render() {
        const {classes, scream:{meme,translation,userImage,userHandle,createdAt,screamId,likeCount,commentCount} }=this.props;
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardMedia
                image={userImage}
                title="Profile Image"/>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{userHandle}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1" color="main">{createdAt}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">{meme}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">{translation}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>  
        )
    }
}
```

I believe that the solution has something to do with JSON.Stringify() to convert the object into string but the methods I have tried, so far have not worked. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What is the value logged in `console.log()`. If you can add it, it would be easy to help you.

Comment: Please show what `res.data` is. My hunch is that the problem is `createdAt`, which is an object with `.seconds` and `.nanoseconds` properties, which you'll need to extract explicitly in your `Scream` component.

Comment: Inside the `Scream` component, print out `this.props.scream` and make sure the data structure is as you expect. I'm guessing one of those object properties is an object when you think it's a string (likely `createdAt`, given the error has time units in it).

Comment: The console log of "res.data" is an object- createdAt: {_seconds: 1568399400, _nanoseconds: 0} @ggorlen

Comment: The console log of "this.props.scream" is an ISOString: ""2019-09-17T16:06:13.051Z" @Jayce444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following ggorlen's comment, What's the response with the following update?

```
 class Scream extends Component {
    render() {
        const {classes, scream } = this.props;
        const {meme,translation,userImage,userHandle,createdAt,screamId,likeCount,commentCount} = scream;
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardMedia
                image={userImage}
                title="Profile Image"/>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{JSON.stringify(userHandle)}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body1" color="main">{JSON.stringify(createdAt)}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">{JSON.stringify(meme)}</Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2">{JSON.stringify(translation)}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>  
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked!! I only had to convert **createdAt** to string

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, based on your error, `createdAt` is an object with the structure

```
{_seconds: 123, _nanoseconds: 456}
```

Change the line

```
<Typography variant="body1" color="main">{createdAt}</Typography>
```

to

```
<Typography variant="body1" color="main">
  {`${createdAt._seconds}:${createdAt._nanoseconds}`}
</Typography>
```

This explicitly pulls the data out of the object and interpolates it into a template string, avoiding the `Objects are not valid as a React child` issue.

Here's a minimal reproduction of the error:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  createdAt = {_seconds: 123, _nanoseconds: 456};
  
  render() {
    return <div>{this.createdAt}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Foo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

and the fix:

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  createdAt = {_seconds: 123, _nanoseconds: 456};

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {`${this.createdAt._seconds}:${this.createdAt._nanoseconds}`}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<Foo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response :) This kind of solves the initial issue as the createdAt is now displayed as follows 1568399400:0. However createdAt is stored in the database as a String in the extended ISO format **2019-09-17T16:06:13.051Z** and I want it to be displayed as stored. @Chris Chen's update worked